# Default translation value in custom Angular library

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I created Angular library and added translation module `@ngx-translate/core` and added keys for it. It works properly for keys that root application translated. But if root application (application where is included my custom library) doesn't have some translated keys from Angular library then that value is displayed like key.

My question is how will I set default value for some key in Angular library and that value will be displayed in library if we don't have that translated key in root application.

This is my code in custom library for included Translate

```
...
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      defaultLanguage: 'en'
    }),
...],
exports: []
})
export class GridPresetModule {
  static config(authenticationKey: () => string,
    SERVER_ADDRESS: () => string,
    SERVER_ADDRESS_NEW: () => string,
    localStorageTokenKey: () => string): ModuleWithProviders<GridPresetModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: GridPresetModule,
      providers: [...]
        };
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Set the [default language](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L169)?

Comment: It isn't issue. Issue is if we have a some translation keys in library but not in root (main) application then I want to show some default value for it key.

Comment: can you please post your code reference, so that it will be easy to find out solution.

Comment: @SachinDane I added my code from module.ts file in custom library